# Xaml files not working properly in my project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

So, the day I turn on my computer every day, start my project, start it today, and then I see the following error:

`An error occurred in "Various files" while trying to open "MainWindow.xaml" No editor is available for 'C: / Users / user / Documents / GitHub \ tetris-game \ tetris-game \ tetris-game \ MainWindow.xaml'.`

I don't know what's going on. I haven't changed anything in the files or uninstalled or installed anything. Maybe I should reinstall VisualStudio?

Comment: Very odd. If you haven't changed any code or settings it's probably a bug in the software. Try re-installing or creating a new project and moving the code.

Comment: @CyanCoding but i don't want to lose all my branches and commits on github.Is there any other solution for this problem?

Comment: Sounds like visual studio no longer has the xaml designer associated with xaml files. Tools > options > xaml designer. Un check and re check if it's checked. See if it works. If not then reset the visual studio settings and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.I opened VS installer and then went to VS 2022, clicked on more and opened the "Repair" function. After this process I restarted my computer, started my project and everything works fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).